# How can I get username and/or id through Instagram API in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client, instagram, instagram-api

I'm not exactly sure how to call methods such as screen name in order to get the username and/or id with Instagram and Ruby:

```
username = Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
  config.client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
  # For secured endpoints only
  #config.client_ips = '<Comma separated list of IPs>'
end

puts username.user
```

Comment: Did you checkout the sample [Sinatra app](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem)? Its pretty straight forward. If you have trouble understanding the demo app than you should probably try some simpler projects first.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to give a link that will take you to Instagram, and you will be asked to enter your username and password, and get verified there.

```
<%= link_to 'Click here to go to Instagram', '/oauth/connect' %>
```

In your routes file,

```
get '/oauth/connect' => 'users#connect'
```

In your `UsersController` class,

```
def connect
  redirect Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)
end
```

`CALLBACK_URL` is crucial here; this is the link Instagram will redirect you once you enter your username and password on Instagram site. When Instagram will hit on your `CALLBACK_URL`, you can do the following to get  the parameters you have asked in your question:

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
user = client.user
username = user.username
```

You can learn about other things at [here](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem).

Comment: where exactly do I type the link at in the .rb file?

Comment: Which .rb file you are talking about? You are supposed to type the code in routes file, as well as in controller file!